# Ignore files while creating a tag in svn

Tags: svn, jenkins, tags

I am trying to find out a way of ignoring certain files while creating a tag from a branch.
I am using subversion-tagging plugin to create a tag. It does a URL to URL copy.
Maybe I can use 'svn copy' command to perform tagging, but there is no option of asking svn or jenkins for that matter to ignore some files while copying.
Also, I would like to decide the files,that has to be ignored, during creating the copy instead of hard-coding it within the command, as the files to be ignored may change.
Any suggestion will be appreciable. Also, please let me know if more information is required.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the entire directory, otherwise it won't show up as a true tag on any system that tracks such things. Or at least, none that I know of.

But you could modify the tag after creation. Nothing actually prevents you from doing that, only convention. So you can create the tag as normal and then remove the files you don't want in the tag.

Just don't get in the habit of regularly updating anything but very well-defined tasks in a tag, for example "locking down" svn:externals to a specific revision, committing generated files, removing these specific files, etc. Actual modifications to the files themselves would defeat the purpose of a tag and should go on a branch instead.